# How to implement conversion operator in c++?

Tags: c++, pointers

**tl;dr;** How to cast a struct/class (or content of it) to specific type?

I want to cast part of an struct/class to some other data type. I've tried to read memory address of struct as a `float` (for example):

```cpp
struct t{ float[3] smthng = {9,1,2,3}; };
struct t tub;
float a = (float*)&tub; // to get an 9;
```

but i got this error:

`error: cannot convert 'float*' to 'float' in initialization`

---

The need for such conversion (`casting`) arised when i wanted to make an stepping struct function that would be able to iterate over floats, and implemented by [`for ranged loop`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) where i couldn't implement `__begin() and __end()` and return an floating point value.

---

How to cast a struct/class (or content of it) to specific type?

Comment: `float[3] smthng = {9,1,2,3};` can't compile as it has too many initializers

Comment: You can't treat memory address as a float. And you should never overload `operator&`. Not clear on the actual question, though.

Comment: It seems that you really overcomplicate this. Just write a getter `float getCurrentValue();` and be done with it.

Comment: NathanOliver yeah sorry it was a pseudo code to illustrate my point. I can change it into something compile-able if needed.
@SergeyA i dont want to treat memory address as a float, i want to read a structure as it is a float.

Comment: @Danilo Take a moment to read about [mcve]. Questions are greatly improved when they are provided.

Comment: Why do you need to treat your structure as float? It has 3 different float members in it, just read the one you are interested in.

Comment: You don’t need to do anything like that to write a generator-thingy. Add an iterator type (you need `*`, `++`, and `!=`), implement `begin` and `end`, and you can range-loop over it, very similarly to Python.

Comment: Because i am doing this for vocal analysis tool. I want to read an audio file of an sound, and then instead of all bunch of data as frequency sample rate and etc. I want to save only which frequencies are where and how loud they are. To do that i need an timer that behaves as a floating point stack. And by reading only first part of the stack you can allways get a time track for defined sample rate and change it without loosing on a quality. @SergeyA

Comment: Look up "Type punning". You'll find that almost any forms of it are Undefined Behaviour in C++. And for good reasons - there are almost always better ways to get to whatever goal you want to get to. You can write "getter" functions, you can write "converting constructors", you can write "operator Type()" functions and more.. Stay within the type system. Don't use casts. Don't type pun.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a conversion operator:

```
struct timer{
    // ...
    operator float() const {
        return curr;
    }
```

This makes the class implicitly convertible:

```
float a = obj;
```

<sub>Technically, the exact syntax of `&obj` is achievable, but overloading the unary `operator&` is horrible design.</sub>

Comment: Thank you. 
Is the *operator()* called automatically when typing "float a = obj" ?

Comment: @Danilo Yes. When an operand types don't match, implicit conversions are resolved. A conversion operator is a user defined conversion.

Comment: Can you help a bit more please: i get this error :  **error: cannot convert 'timer' to 'float' in initialization**.

Comment: @Danilo My example had the syntax wrong. It's now fixed

Answer (score 1):

While [the answeer by @eerorika](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54637838/434551) provides an excellent working solution, I think it will be better to use a more direct approach to get the current time instead of relying on a cast operator.

```
struct timer
{
    // ...
    float getCurrentTime() const
    {
        return curr;
    }
}
```

---

```
Timer timer;
float cur = timer.getCurrentTime();
```

is more readable than

```
Timer timer;
float cur = timer;
```